# SharePoint is the most dreaded platform?

Tags: discussion

I was taking a look through the [Stack Overflow Developer Survey Results](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017#overview) and noticed that SharePoint was the most dreaded platform.

[image]

Is this a common feeling throughout the community, or more of an outside looking in thing?

Comment: SharePoint is different and doesn't work as a regular ASP.NET application. That's why it's hated by many, but loved by even more. Especially those who know SharePoint.

Comment: Also, because it's so robust and a big platform with a lot of limitations, gotchas and you have to do things a certain way. ASP.NET developers find that they can bring over a little info, but a lot they have to learn. It is quite a lot to know about developing in SharePoint. I mean we one of few platforms to have our own certifications for development AND administration.

Comment: Two years running! https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=meta&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2018-promotion#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-platforms

Comment: The only people who don't dread SharePoint are (1) business managers who select it based on a magic OOTB demo and then never use it themselves and (2) SharePoint consultants who sell it to said business managers.  Ask any developer that doesn't fit into category #2 and you'll find that SharePoint development is essentially throwing hacks on top of heaps of legacy code of an incomplete product.  If you want the truth read this article and then read the scathing comments afterwards (https://en.share-gate.com/blog/no-you-are-wrong-sharepoint-doesnt-suck).